LDAP retrieve the groups in which a user belongs to
I need to get the groups in which a user belongs to. I’ve read the documentation, but it is not too clear for me.
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/ldap-component.html#_query_parameters
There is an example in doc

Collection<SearchResult> results = template.requestBody(
    "ldap:ldapserver?base=ou=mygroup,ou=groups,ou=system",
    "(member=uid=huntc,ou=users,ou=system)", Collection.class);

if (results.size() > 0) {
  // Extract what we need from the device's profile

  Iterator<SearchResult> resultIter = results.iterator();
  SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) resultIter.next();
  Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
  Attribute deviceCNAttr = attributes.get("cn");
  String deviceCN = (String) deviceCNAttr.get();
  // ...

Are the groups declared as attributes in the searchResult? And in the request why is specified ou=mygroup ou=groups ou=system?
Thanks for advance

I think, it's not a problem with the camel component, but with the ldap protocol itself, which is not that clear. The ou=mygroup ou=groups ou=system is being read from right to left as a hierarchy. ou means organizational unit and is a logical layer. So thss ldap will search in system/groups/mygroup (will return groups) where system/users/uid = 'huntc' and this user is member of. So this will return a list of SearchResults, each including a list of Attribute. The cn is the common name of the entry which is the group name.

Do you get any errors? For getting the structure, you can just do a loop and print every attribute. Then you should see, wich values you want. If there is a specific issue, post your actual code. Of course, you need knowledge about your ldap directory structure, to build your actual query string.

@Raphi1 is correct.  You need to look further at you LDAP structure if this is not working for you.  For example, your membership attribute might be uniqueMember, not simply member.  The search (member=uid=huntc,ou=users,ou=system) presumes that all objects under ou=mygroup,ou=groups,ou=system have an attribute member.  You may well need to tighten up your search with something like &(objectClass=group)(member=uid=huntc,ou=users,ou=system).  This means to search only in the group objects.  As before, your may have groupOfUniqueNames and uniqueMember.
